As a wrapper object in JavaScript, why can not use 'new' to create a BigInt in JavasScript?
There are 5 wrapper objects in JavaScript: Number, BigInt, String, Boolean, and Symbol.You can use 'new' to create a Number, String, Boolean, Symbol. But you can not use 'new' to create a BigInt. what is the story behind it?
I want to know the story behind it. If they are primitive types, what are these types: number, bigint, string, and symbol, etc.

You cannot create new Symbol.

You're focusing on the opposite thing here. There is no real issue that new doesn't work with BigInt. But there have been issues when new was used with Number, String, and Boolean. So, BigInt and Symbol are the sensible ones of the bunch. So, you're asking why aren't they worse by being callable with new. Instead of focusing on why new should even be allowed.
